# proper way to configure paperclip's bucket option for S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to upload and display images from an S3 bucket to my rails 4 app on heroku. I want to add an image when creating 'Designer' object

I am using paperclip. In `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

I set the config variables

```
$ heroku config
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:            AKIAI...HVWD2YQ
AWS_BUCKET:                   myafricastyle
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:        VFgFVF4.....gKnT5AMFtP4
```

This is the model I want to add images to:

```
class Designer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items, dependent: :destroy 

    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
        thumb: '100x100>',
        square: '200x200#',
        medium: '300x300>'
    }                       
end
```

I have a migration to add the images to the Designer table..

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToDesigners < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :designers do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :designers, :avatar
  end
end
```

When I try to add the Designer with an uploaded photo I get:

```
$ heroku logs

[paperclip] saving /designers/avatars/000/000/016/original/moto_ninjas87.jpg
[paperclip] saving /designers/avatars/000/000/016/original/moto_ninjas87.jpg
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2622ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2622ms
app/controllers/designers_controller.rb:33:in `block in create'
app/controllers/designers_controller.rb:33:in `block in create'
app/controllers/designers_controller.rb:32:in `create'

ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):
ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):
app/controllers/designers_controller.rb:32:in `create'
```

What's wrong with my bucket option configuration?

**addition:**
my `controllers/designers_controller.rb` shows:

```
  def create
    @designer = Designer.new(designer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @designer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @designer, notice: 'Designer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @designer }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @designer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_designer
      @designer = Designer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def designer_params
      params.require(:designer).permit(:name, :country, :about, :avatar)
    end
```

I have both the `aws-sdk` and `paperclip` gems installed

Comment: What's in your `DesignersController#create` method, line 32-33? Have you added the `aws-sdk` gem?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the bucket in the hash that is passed to s3_credentials. Also you should consider moving config to yml file and load it from there.

```
:storage => :s3, 
:path => "/archive/:style/:id/:filename", 
:s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml')
```

s3.yml file

```
production:
   bucket:  <%= ENV['S3_BUCKET'] %>
   access_key_id:   <%= ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
   secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following happens because you are calling @designer.save in the create method, and paperclip adds a post-create hook to your designer class.

```
ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):
app/controllers/designers_controller.rb:32:in `create'
```

To fix it, I think that

```
:bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
```

belongs one level up in the hash. So:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
   :storage => :s3,
   :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
   :s3_credentials => {
       :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
       :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
   }
}
```

For more info, see:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3